# Is there a way to obtain WASAPI loopback recordings using MediaStream Recording API?

Tags: reactjs, loopback, recording, mediastream, wasapi

The first question on StackOverflow after many years of copypasting!

Do you know how to access the Windows WASAPI driver in order to obtain audio loopback capabilities on React?

Tried out using methods such as listing devices (e.g. mediaDevices.enumerateDevices()) on an Electron + React.js application, but haven't got any results yet.

If it's not possible, why?